# What is the best possible approach (faster) to store and retrieve 3 values for calculating distance?

Tags: database, numpy, tuples, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have a data with around 500,1000 rows.

Each row is of the format :

```
id1    id2    distance

296    237    0.33
296    274    0.67
296    260    0.9
237    123    0.2
```

Whenever a new id comes in I have to find the distance between the new id and the ids from the data and get the shortest 100 distances.

How should I save the already computed distances?
Should I save it as a csv and read it every time a new image comes in.

For example if a new id 200 comes in, after calculating the distance between each id and the new id, I add it back to the csv.

Is csv the fastest approach? If not what would be the best way to retrieve the ids and the distances?

id1 and id2 are images. The distance is the Euclidean distance.

There are around 500,000 rows

Comment: How do you define distance? Is it one ID minus the other? And is it 500-1000 rows, or 500,000? The rest depends on your data. Is this the only thing you store? You might be able to get away with a file if its 500 lines. But all depends on what else you are storing. Normally trying to simulate a DBMS in your own code is not the best idea, but depends on your situation.

Comment: added comments to the question

Comment: So given an id, how do I find its location? But at 500k rows, its definitely going to be a database of some sort.

Comment: Maybe you could do something with [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) and [Memory](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html#memory) if you are willing to add Scikit-Learn as a dependency.